# /etc/crypttab ignored on boot

Tags: boot, encryption, luks, dmcrypt

I wanted to setup encryption with dm-crypt and LUKS, but I set it up manually, not during installation process (I created LUKS partition and /etc/crypttab file properly). But the encrypted partition defined in /etc/crypttab doesn't mount at boot at all. Otherwise, when mounted manually, everything works.

It was a clean Ubuntu 13.10 install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that only package `cryptsetup-bin` is installed by default on ubuntu 13.10 (and AFAIK on older versions). That means, that you can create and manipulate dm-crypt partitions, but you also need `cryptsetup` package, which contains startup scripts for mounting dm-crypt volumes at boot.

`sudo apt-get install cryptsetup` solved that problem.